# How to trigger even or schedule task when windows is restarting or shutting down, and force windows to wait until some actions to be done

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to perform some actions in my windows service which I have developed in C# when user is restarting or shutting down his computer,

so I need to transfer some file to server (about 5 file, each one is 60 MB), so I need my service tp force windows to wait until tranferring is finished.

an idea just came to my mind, how to schedule task for windows? so the best thing for me is to do something looks like windows update screen in c#, so windows will wait to copy these files? or at least I need to triiger an even in my windows service when windows is restarting or shutting down and winodws will wait until files are transferred.

C# or VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

to block shutdown, you can use api function like ShutdownBlockReasonCreate but it is not a good practice to do so.
The best way for you is to change your workflow, you can make a schedule job that every minutes  add new record in your server, so your data will be saved...

Comment: but the problem is network, I will install this software to 500 computers and if each minute there is file transferring, workers will find network is slow, so I need before any of them will shut down or restarting his computer, I want to perform schedule task to execute a console application or any service to send files ...

Comment: I understand, but it will be better not to send a file in one time. imagine 500 computers shuting down at the same time and sending whole files... it is better to send not whole file but few lines every time from your different computer